# What's the mean natural action ?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a soluble group by $ \Phi(G) = 1 $ that $ \Phi(G) $ is the Frattini subgroup of $ G $.Let $ N $ is the unique normal minimal subgroup of $ G $ and $ M $ be a maximal subgroup of $ G $. Hence $ M_{G} = 1 $ such that $ M_{G} $ is the core of $ M $ in $ G $. Suppose $ \vert N \vert = 4 $. We consider the natural action of $ G $ on the right cosets of $ M $ in $ G $. Then $ G(\cong G/M_{G}) $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $ S_{4} $. What's the mean natural action in here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural action on right cosets is by right multiplication, i.e. $g$ maps the coset $Mx$ to the coset $M(xg)$.